# High negative voltage cut-off for op-amp from dual-rail power supply

Tags: circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection, reverse-polarity, negative-voltage, dual-supply

[image: Dual Rail Supply with Reverse-Polarity Protection and Positive Voltage Cutoff]

In the picture I have a circuit that prevents reverse polarity and cuts the voltage with respect to the Zener diode (15 V) as a voltage reference for positive voltage output.

How do I apply the same thing towards the negative voltage which cuts at 15 V at the bottom of the picture just by using transistors? Other options for the circuit are also appreciated.

Comment: How much current will be needed by your OpAmp circuit? Are there additional loads connected?